16 word seed phrase
in 2014 she had a wallet, I don't remember where she created it but she has a 16-word seed phrase.
these do not match the BIP39 list.
How can I know which protocol they belong to? so I can recover my wallet.
Thank you

Under BIP39 it could be a 15 words with a password.
